# Cannot print pdf format in android

Tags: android

When I print pdf file by using the following code in android, print output is not correctly,

Here is my code ,

```
private class PrintFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... result) {

           FileInputStream fileInputStream;
           BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = null;

        File file = new File(DB_PATH);

         try {
         Socket client = new Socket("172.230.1.16", 9100);

         byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) file.length()];

         fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
         bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);

         bufferedInputStream.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
         outputStream = client.getOutputStream();

         outputStream.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length); //
         outputStream.flush();
         bufferedInputStream.close();
         outputStream.close();
         client.close();

         } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Text format(.txt) is OK.This is sample output for pdf,

```
1 0 obj
       << /Creater (Prawn)
                         /Producre (Prawn)
                                          >> endobj
                                                   2 0 obj
                                                          ......
```

or something like that. How can I solve it.

Comment: You are printing binary data. You should use action view intent. with mime type "application/pdf".

Comment: how to use it. Where I will edit ? Can I get sample code?

Answer (score -1):

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ filename);
Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // Instruct the user to install a PDF reader here, or something
}
```

Comment: @ arjun.9990 , Firstly , I would like to say thank for answer my question. But I still not found solution for pdf file print via wifi. I try to use your code in my method , it is only intend to open pdf file . Not for print. It may be my fault because I am fresher in android programming. So if your have detail solution or other way , please let me know.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.jsecurity.printbot this is what you want to do? you may use Epson Brother Canon Lexmark Postscript. Open API for 3rd party apps. i don't know any details. you have to study it.